# how to insert a new service into docker-compose.yml using sed

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, sed

I want to add a new service into docker-compose.yml with bash. this is how it looks:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if the file exists
if [ ! -f "docker-compose.yml" ]; then
  echo "Error: docker-compose.yml file not found"
  exit 1
fi

#insert new service into docker-compose.yml
new_service=$(cat << SERVICE
# New service section
new_service:
  image: some_image
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
SERVICE
)

# Check if the service already exists
if grep -q "^new_service:" docker-compose.yml; then
  echo "Service 'new_service' exists in docker-compose.yml"
else
  echo "Service 'new_service' does not exist in docker-compose.yml, inserting"
  sed -i "/# New service section/a ${new_service}" docker-compose.yml
  echo "Service section added to docker-compose.yml"
fi
```

this looks straight forward but throws:

```
Service 'new_service' does not exist in docker-compose.yml, inserting
sed: -e expression #1, char 49: extra characters after command
Service section added to docker-compose.yml
```

I created a very basic docker-compose.yml file but sed still complains, so maybe there is a better approach?

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
# New service section
```

Comment: `#insert new service into docker-compose.yml` <- no it doesn't, you're just assigning a string to a variable. I think you're just asking how to append text to a file in bash, this isn't related to docker nor sed

Comment: I'd probably just `cat` the fragment on to the end of the file in this case.  But, it needs to be correctly indented, and you need a guarantee that the last top-level block is `services:`.  Another tool might be better for this.  Possibly easier is using [multiple Compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can try using `awk` For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

old_dc=$(cat docker-compose.yml)

new_service=$(cat << SERVICE
  new_service:
    image: some_image
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
SERVICE
)

new_dc=$(echo "$old_dc" | awk -v var="$new_service" '/services:/ {p=1} {print} p && /services:/ {print var; p=0}')

echo "$new_dc" > docker-compose.yml
```

Comment: thanks, this seems to be the only solution that reliably works. Just catting the service to the end of the file would work, but YAML intendation this way seems to be impossible. So, thanks again.